# Trying to connect to AWS Kinesis from boto.kinesis; us-west-1 doesn't work, but other regions do

Tags: boto, amazon-kinesis

I'm using [`boto`](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/) to connect to ASW Kinesis. For some reason, the connections to "us-west-2" and "us-east-1" work, but not for "us-west-1":

```
from boto import kinesis

con = kinesis.connect_to_region("us-west-1")
print con  # None

con = kinesis.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
print con  # KinesisConnection:kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com

con = kinesis.connect_to_region("us-east-1")
print con  # KinesisConnection:kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The credentials are stored in the `~/.boto` file.

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like boto has not yet been updated to support that new Kinesis endpoint.  If you look in your boto distribution, there is a file called `endpoints.json` and it contains information about which services are available in which regions.  It currently does not list the `us-west-1` region for the Kinesis service.

You could manually add it to your distribution or you could create an issue with the boto project.

Comment: I modified the `endpoints.json` file and simply added the us-west-1 region as you suggested; and it worked. I now can connect and create streams.